# Shinydashboard dashboardSidebar Width Setting

Tags: css, r, width, shiny

I'm using **shiny** (0.12.0) with **[shinydashboard](http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/)** (0.4.0) in **R** (RRO 8.0.3 CRAN-R 3.1.3) to create a UI, and I'm liking what I'm seeing. However, I would like to be able to control the width of the `dashboardSidebar` item, since I need to put some wide selector boxes in there.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(#stuffhere)  #would like a width param setting
  dashboardBody()
)
```

Is there a way to do it (some well-hidden width parameter, or embedded css) or do I have to go back to boring shiny and build it from the ground up instead?

[image: Sad skinny panel needs more meat]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The old answer might still work, but there is also a `width = ...` option now. See:
https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#sidebar-width. Here is the example code shown over there:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = "Title and sidebar 350 pixels wide",
      titleWidth = 350
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      width = 350,
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Menu Item")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Answer (score 9):

The width of the sidebar is set by CSS on the `.left-side` class, so you could do:

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar( tags$style(HTML("
      .main-sidebar{
        width: 300px;
      }
    ")),selectInput("id","Select a survey",choices=c("Very very very very long text","text"))), 
    dashboardBody()
  )
```

Comment: did that work for you? It didn't change the format for me. I'll try a few variations.

Comment: yeah works for me, maybe we don't have the same `shinydashboard` versions, I'm running `shinydashboard_0.2.3` and `shiny_0.11.1.9005`

Comment: .left-side didn't work. Did an inspect on the page, tried the same with .main-sidebar{  ... } and that worked!

Comment: yes, I updated my packages and the class of the sidebar is now `main-sidebar`

Comment: In order to get everything to look right, I had to add the following css to the `dashboardBody` function: `tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
     .main-sidebar{
       width: 300px;
     }
     .main-header > .navbar {
       margin-left: 300px;
     }
     .main-header .logo {
        width: 300px;
     }
     .content-wrapper, .main-footer, .right-side {
         margin-left: 300px;
     }
   ')))`